# What are the prime and non-prime attributes in this relation?

Tags: database-design, normalization

```
R(HIJKLMNO)

L -> MNO
HI -> JKLMNO
J -> KL
K -> H
```

HI is a key.

So, H is a prime attribute.

But, H is also in non-key part.

What are the prime and non-prime attributes in this relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your schema has three (candidate) keys:

```
HI
IJ
IK
```

While it is immediate to discover tha `HI` is a candidate key since it determines all the other attributes, you can see that this is true also for `IJ` and `IK` by calculating the closure of those attributes:

```
IJ+ = IJ
IJ+ = IJKL     (by adding the right part of J → KL)
IJ+ = IJKLH    (by adding the rigth part of K → H)
IJ+ = IJKLHMNO (by adding the right part of L → MNO)
```

analogously for `IK`:

```
IK+ = IK
IK+ = IKH      (by adding the rigth part of K → H)
IK+ = IKHJLMNO (by adding the right part of HI → JKLMNO)
```

For this reason, the prime attributes of the relation are:

```
HIJK
```

while the non prime attributes are:

```
LMNO
```

Note that there are no other candidate keys since `M`, `N` and `O` appear only on the right side of functional dependencies, so that they cannot “contribute” to any key. `L` appears both on a left part and on a right part of functional dependencies, but it is determined by `HI`, `IJ` and `IK`, and does *not* determine any of these attributes, so it cannot be part of a key. Finally, you cannot remove any attribute from `HI`, `IJ` and `IK` without losing the key property.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to find out possible candidate keys. `HI` is the only possible candidate key or prime attribute since it independently identifies all other attributes or fields due to the functional dependency `HI -> JKLMNO`.

All the other attributes are non-prime attributes. Again, here `HI` is a composite candidate key and both H and I are key attributes together forming the primary key.

All other attributes are dependent on `HI` together, else it will result in `partial function dependency (PFD)` or, in other words, the criteria for 2nd Normal Form won't be satisfied.

Comment: Your solution is not correct, there are other candidate keys.